# How to assign the column name to the variable dynamically

Tags: r

I am currently developing an application and I need to loop through the columns of the data frame. For instance, if the data frame has the columns

```
char_set <- data.frame(character(),character(),character(),character(),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
names(char_set) <-  c("a","b","c","d")
```

If the input is given as "a", then the column name "b" should be assigned to the variable, say promote. 
It throws an error `Error in`[.data.frame`(char_set, i + 1) : undefined columns selected`.  Is there any solution?

```
char_name <- "a"
char_set <- data.frame(character(),character(),character(),character(),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
names(char_set) <-  c("a","b","c","d")
for (i in 1:ncol(char_set)) {
  promote <- ifelse(names(char_set) == char_name,char_set[i+1], "-")
  print(promote)
}
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: So your issue is with the `ifelse` statement?

Comment: Can you update with the expected output?

Comment: Since "a" is given as input in "char_name", the variable "promote" should have the value "b". If the input is given as "c", then the output should be "d" @RLave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually quite interesting. I would suggest doing something on those lines:

```
char_name <- "a"
char_set <- data.frame(
    a = 1:2,
    b = 3:4,
    c = 5:6,
    d = 8:9,
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
res_dta <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 2, ncol = 3))
for (i in wrapr::seqi(1, NCOL(char_set) - 1)) {
    print(i)
    if (names(char_set)[i] == char_name) {
        res_dta[i] <- char_set[i + 1]
    } else {
        res_dta[i] <- char_set[i]
    }
}
```

### Results

```
char_set
  a b c d
1 1 3 5 8
2 2 4 6 9
res_dta
  X1 X2 X3
1  3  3  5
2  4  4  6
```

There are few generic points:

- When you are looping through columns be mindful not fall outside data frame dimensions; running `i + 1` on `i = 4` will give you column 5 which will return an error for data frame with four columns. You may then decide to run to one column less or break for a specific `i` value
- Not sure if I got your request right, for column names `a` you want to take values of column `b`; then column `b` stays as it was?

  - Broadly speaking, I'm of a view that this `names(char_set)[i] == char_name` requires more thought but you have a start with this answer. Updating your post with desired results would help to design a solution.

Comment: Rather than getting the values of the specific column, can we get the name of the column alone?

Comment: @NevedhaAyyanar Yes, names(data)[i] will give you that

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that you are looping from 1 to the number of columns of the `char_set` df, then you are calling the variable `char_set[i+1]`. 
This, when the `i` index takes the maximum value, the instruction `char_set[i+1]` returns an error because there is no element with that index.

You can try with this solution:

```
char_name<-"a"

promote<-ifelse((which(names(char_set)==char_name)+1)<ncol(char_set),names(char_set)[which(names(char_set)==char_name)+1],"-")

promote
> [1] "b"

char_name<-"d"

promote<-ifelse((which(names(char_set)==char_name)+1)<ncol(char_set),names(char_set)[which(names(char_set)==char_name)+1],"-")
promote

> [1] "-"
```

However. when the variable char_name takes the value `a`, the variable promote will take the value that the set `char_set` has at the position after the element named `a`, which matches `char_name`.

I suggest you to think about the case in which the variable `char_name` takes the value `d` and you don't have any values in the `char_set` after `d`.